# Use different formula based on group element count with geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a plot and add a geom_smooth line for each group.

But since every group has a different number of elements (and I don't know beforehand how many elements each group would have, nor how many groups would be), a different formula needs to be applied based on the number of elements in order to create a good plot. If there are less than 4 elements in the group, a linear formula 'y~x' would be preferable. If there are 4 or more elements, a logaritmic formula 'log(x,2)' should be the chosen one.

The df is:

```
> dput(df)


structure(list(ticker = c("X18O3", "X23N3", "X18E4", "TX24", 
"T2X4", "TX26", "TX28", "T4X4", "T2X5", "T3X4", "DICP", "PARP", 
"CUAP", "T5X4", "TX25", "TDJ24C", "TV24", "T2V4", "TDA24", "TDG24", 
"TDF24"), date = structure(c(19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 
19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 
19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634, 19634), class = "Date"), 
    price = c(138.6, 130.4, 110.5, 600.5, 421.5, 426.5, 399.9, 
    157, 131, 154, 9250, 4126.5, 5500, 113.2, 236.7, 108.574003326365, 
    98.4714285714286, 99.9285714285714, 101.357142857143, 97.5714285714286, 
    100.285714285714), group = c("lecer", "lecer", "lecer", "bonosCER", 
    "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", 
    "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", "bonosCER", 
    "bonosCER", "Dual CER", "Dolar Linked", "Dolar Linked", "Dolar Linked", 
    "Dolar Linked", "Dolar Linked"), yield = c(0.0218045090120585, 
    0.298651958153468, 0.0604351964422699, 0.185448548003098, 
    0.219670799244788, 0.191998162688335, 0.183859622993311, 
    0.0872520516162154, 0.220277946950198, 0.16975041781472, 
    0.0979981157973123, 0.111603679380766, 0.107834486670947, 
    0.194626244415027, 0.11522059367659, -0.0105889806782128, 
    0.034854793659985, 0.00580418334812509, -0.0234891005691207, 
    0.0276510660236494, -0.00715613534868776), mduration = c(0.0321751490023804, 
    0.10126412122156, 0.268692993032721, 0.395203276830626, 0.721958092439503, 
    1.78343089982253, 2.21642150599435, 0.949091399584694, 1.19421145862223, 
    0.437480985523567, 4.04326102756222, 8.28799990573452, 9.84200427417035, 
    1.04800509583345, 1.92878801122986, 0.742104707754085, 0.547040297182039, 
    0.982405082332295, 0.580764933603675, 0.877116652543917, 
    0.400123612701299)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

My approach was to write something like this:

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mduration, y = yield, color = group, group = group, label = ticker)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(
      method = 'lm',
      formula = ifelse(n() < 4, 'y~x', 'y~log(x,2)'),
      se = FALSE
    )
```

But I receive the error: Error in `n()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.

I was trying to use n() to determine how many rows in each group to select the appropriate function to use.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use purrr::map to plot? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751295/how-to-plot-lines-selected-by-indices-from-dataframe-on-the-same-graph-with-ggpl

Answer (score 2):

I tried to modify the code from [How to change linetype conditional on x-axis factor in ggplot when using geom_smooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225895/11124121)

```
library(magrittr)

df %<>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(n = n())

ggplot(df, aes(x = mduration, y = yield, color = group, group = group, label = ticker)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=df[df$n < 4 ,], method = 'lm',  formula = 'y~x',se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=df[df$n > 3 ,],  method = 'lm', formula =  'y~log(x,2)', se = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I got tangled up and didn't see it. It was simpler.